# Is there any other method to output variable content in php?

Tags: php, html, css, sass

I did a setup of scssphp in my framework and made it working with multiple files. Below is the code of how it output itself as text/css.

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/css');
ob_clean();



function scss_css() {
require "../SCSS-PHP/scss.inc.php";
$import_way = "../styles/scss/";
$compression = "scss_formatter_compressed";
$compiler_script = '@import "demo.scss"'; 

$scss = new scssc();
$scss->setImportPaths($import_way);
$scss->setFormatter($compression);

echo $scss->compile($compiler_script);
}
scss_css();
die();

?>
```

The call i used in html is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="binder/loader.scss.php">
```

I would like to know if `echo` is safe for my future working scss setup. Can there be any attack on such a file output and any other suggestions to make it better?

Comment: Instead of output in php why you don't save the compressed file

Comment: Output is in css,and it is running successfully with 20 files minified in single css, look at the headers, i just want to know if there is any better way i can construct the above code.Thanks

Comment: Echo is safe assuming that the total scss files and intermediate data structures can be held in memory.  One thing that may be worth doing is to use some sort of service side caching mechanism to store the results of your $scss->compile($compiler_script) command to avoid having perform the compilation on every request.

Comment: are you saying that i have to use apache htaccess cache control for loader.scss.php file. I tried inspection and most of the times flag 200 was set over that file so i think it is working in that manner